# HEVC video playback on Chrome with Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't work

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome, hevc

I'm aware that Chrome added HEVC support in October 2022, and this appears to work on my Windows PC, however playback of the same video isn't working on my `Ubuntu 22.04` laptop.

I'm using `Chrome Version 109.0.5414.119` (Official Build) (64-bit).

The chipset of the PC is `12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1260P`

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install the necessary codecs for HEVC playback? Try this command:

`sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra`

Comment: Or maybe the x265 package will do the trick? https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/x265